# Populate listview along with text and onitemclick intent to new layout containing another listview along with text based on the selection

Tags: android, listview, count, custom-adapter

**I need a listview  containing cities along with their area count (ie) 
 Bangalore(10)  Delhi(5) Mumbai(15) one by one likethis.
 Onclicking each cities i need a another listview containing those areas along with the count of shops in that area..(ie) If i click bangalore it displays listview of 10 areas along with count of shops in that each area....(ex) area1(10)  area2(20)  area3(25) likethis..**

> help me with the sample code to display (listview and text)
>   onitemclick on another (listview and text)....and also to display the
>   text with parenthesis () Example:: Bangalore(10)

I have attached my code :

**TextListViewActivity::**

```
public class TextListViewActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {
    int chn_len,mum_len,cal_len;
    String[]  city;
    String[] descriptions;

    ListView listView1;
    List<RowItem> rowItems1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        city = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city_array);
        chn_len=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.area_chennai).length;
        mum_len=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.area_mumbai).length;
        cal_len=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.area_calcutta).length;
         descriptions = new String[] {String.valueOf(chn_len),String.valueOf(mum_len),String.valueOf(cal_len)};


        rowItems1 = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(city[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems1.add(item);
        }

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter1 = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, rowItems1);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

    }
}
```

**CustomListViewAdapter::**

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                                 List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        //ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle1;
        TextView txtDesc1;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtDesc1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.txtTitle1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
           // holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtDesc1.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
        holder.txtTitle1.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
       // holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**RowItem:**

```
public class RowItem {
   // private int imageId;
    private String title;
    private String desc;

    public RowItem(String title, String desc) {
      //  this.imageId = imageId;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
  /*  public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }*/
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc1) {
        this.desc = desc1;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title1) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + "\n" + desc;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TextListViewActivity::**

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("object", rowItems1.get(position));
            Intent intent = new Intent(TextListViewActivity .this,TextListViewDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**TextListViewDetailActivity::**

get city data from intent as shown below.

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
    if (bundle != null) {
        RowItem model = (RowItem) bundle.getSerializable("object");
    }
```

here in the model, you will have city data. Use it to fetch area data and populate it in the listview.

**RowItem:**

```
public class RowItem implements Serializable  {
....
}
```

just add implements Serializable to your RowItem class.

Comment: According to my code how will i populate the count in listview along with paranthesis?? like this -> Bangalore(10) but now i m getting Bangalore 10 @Maharith Aditya S S

Comment: Append data as string and then set text in adapter YOURTEXT_VIEW.setText(CITYNAME+"("+COUNT+")");

Comment: String City_Count = CITYNAME+"("+COUNT+")"; YOURTEXT_VIEW.setText(City_Count );